# JSDocs comments being removed while autogenerating a .d.ts file for a const JavaScript namespace

Tags: javascript, typescript, .d.ts

I am currently trying to autogenerate .d.ts files for my JavaScript API using --declaration and I am running into problems. All of the files which use a const namespace will have all of their comments removed, including the JSDocs ones. For example,

```
/**
 * Foo namespace
 * @namespace
 */
const Foo = {
    /** Test function */
    foo: function() {},
    /** Test property */
    bar: 1
}
```

gets converted to

```
declare namespace Foo {
    function foo(): void;
    const bar: number;
}
```

instead of

```
 /**
  * Foo namespace
  * @namespace
  */
 declare namespace Foo {
    /** Test function */
    function foo(): void;
    /** Test property */
    const bar: number;
 }
```

Not exactly sure what is causing this issue and how to get about solving it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the `removeComments` option set?

Comment: It has been set to false. I sanity checked it by a class with comments and all of the comments were retained in the class, but not the namespace.